# Can you write between/3 in pure prolog?

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I've been trying to understand how to produce a series of values from a Prolog predicate on backtracking. The builtin predicate `between/3` will generate all the integers in a range one at a time on backtracking, so an example of how that is written may help me with my task.

I looked for an implementation in an existing Prolog system, but the implementation of `between/3` for GNU Prolog is a C function, and the trick there is that it calls another C function "Pl_Create_Choice_Point" which allows it to produce additional values on backtracking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
bet(N, M, K) :- N =< M, K = N.
bet(N, M, K) :- N < M, N1 is N+1, bet(N1, M, K).
```

In action:

```
$ swipl
?- [bet].
% bet compiled 0.00 sec, 1,064 bytes
true.

?- bet(1,5, K).
K = 1 n
K = 2 n
K = 3 n
K = 4 n
K = 5 n
false.
```

If you use a cut, you can prevent the final search failure, and recover the exact builtin between/3 behavior:

```
bet(N, M, K) :- N < M, K = N.
bet(N, M, K) :- N == M, !, K = N.
bet(N, M, K) :- N < M, N1 is N+1, bet(N1, M, K).
```

In action:

```
?- [bet].
% bet compiled 0.00 sec, 416 bytes
true.

?- between(1,5,K).
K = 1 n
K = 2 n
K = 3 n
K = 4 n
K = 5.

?- [bet].
% bet compiled 0.00 sec, 240 bytes
true.

?- bet(1,5,K).
K = 1 n
K = 2 n
K = 3 n
K = 4 n
K = 5.
```

Comment: Your initial version was a bit better, as it didn't fail at the end.

Answer (score 7):

What you're really asking is how to create a choice point. You get a solution whenever you have a successful unification. That's what happens in @seanmcl's first predicate:

```
bet(N, M, K) :- N =< M, K = N.
```

To get a choice point, you need to have alternatives. There are only two ways to get an alternative in Prolog: with an explicit "or": `;`, or by supplying another rule. @seanmcl's code gives another rule, which is idiomatic for this situation.

To give another example, `member/2` generates a solution for every item in the list, but there's no magic C function needed, just two rules:

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|Xs]) :- member(X, Xs).
```

Let's look at what happens here with `member(X, [1,2])`. First, the first rule is used and `[X|_]` is unified with `[1,2]`, producing `X=1`, `_=[2]`. This is a successful unification, so a solution is generated. If this fails (such as by you pressing `;` at the console), backtracking is initiated. The next choice point is between the two rules, so the next rule is entered. `[_|Xs]` unifies with [1,2], producing the binding `Xs=[2]` and then `member(X, [2])` is called. Upon re-entry, the same decisions are available to be made again, so the first rule `member(X, [X|_])` is applied and the `X=2` binding is produced. This is a solution. If you backtrack again, you'll get a harmless failure because neither of the rules unify with `[]`.

I hope this helps make sense of the situation a little bit.