# Prolog: between/3 with a list at the end

Tags: list, prolog, between

my question comes up because of this question
[Can you write between/3 in pure prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337235/can-you-write-between-3-in-pure-prolog)

would it be possible to make between/3 and the third argument is a list so if you ask

```
between(2,6,X).
```

it comes

```
X=[2,3,4,5,6]
```

and not like

```
X=2
X=3
X=4
....
```

I can’t figure out how this must work (all my solutions don’t work..)
I’m a Prolog beginner so I have no idea..

sorry for the bad English..

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by going to the library and getting a good book, for example "The Art of Prolog" by Sterling and Shapiro.

Two ways:

```
?- findall(X, between(2, 6, X), Xs).
Xs = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
```

You should also take a look at `bagof/3` and `setof/3`.

For a direct way, `numlist/3`, see for example [the SWI-Prolog implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/lists.pl?show=src). Without argument checking it comes down to:

```
numlist(U, U, List) :- !,
    List = [U].
numlist(L, U, [L|Ns]) :-
    L2 is L+1,
    numlist(L2, U, Ns).
```

There are several ways to break the predicate as it stands.

```
?- numlist(1,0,L).
```

will not terminate. You need to either check the arguments before passing them to this particular version of `numlist/3`:

```
must_be(integer, L),
must_be(integer, U),
L =< U
```

These checks are incorporated in the library predicate `numlist/3` from the linked SWI-Prolog implementation.