# Prolog - Multiplying A list with an uninstantiated list

Tags: prolog

The input to this predicate is S, a list of integers I, and a list of integers T. Assumption is that both S and I are fully instantiated, but not T. The function multiplies the the first element in I with the first element in T then sums it with the second element in I multiplied with the [...] you get the idea. However, the struggle I am having is making this function succeed when T isn't instantiated it. I don't want to use `use_module(library(clpfd))` even though it may be easier. 
I already have something which multiplies correctly, as a helper. To get rid of the "uninstantiated variable" issue I figured I let a variable = S div head of I, so I'd instantiate a new variable, and I'd do this for each item in list I. Then I'd generate all the permutations such that the multiplication of items in a list summed results to S

```
mult_prod(A, B, S) :-
    sum_prod(A, B, 0, S).
mult_prod([A | As], [B | Bs], Accum, S) :-
    Accum1 is Accum + A*B,
    mult_prod(As, Bs, Accum1, S).
mult_prod([], [], Accum, Accum).


multSum(S, I, T) :-
```

Comment: Stop calling them functions, they are not :) but really, a Prolog predicate is not a function. And again, you don't show even an attempt at solving it yourself. You can at least try something, right? Otherwise, this question looks like one of those "fill in the blanks" that lazy professors give to their students.

Comment: This isn't for school. It is strictly for my learning. I agree I should try something at least and matter of fact, I did try something :) I wrote mult_prod which actually solves the question. However, when I have T uninstantiated, it won't work, as I get the complaint of uninstantiated variable.

Comment: Alright Boris. I actually did write code but it became a total mess. However, to get rid of the "uninstantiated variable" issue I figured I let a variable = S div head of I, so I'd instantiate a new variable, and I'd do this for each item in list I. Then I'd generate all the permutations such that the multiplication of items in a list summed results to S.

Comment: Didn't want to make it so lengthy. Lengthy sometimes means no one read unfortunately, but there I added it Boris :)

Comment: That's better :-) The previous question you asked: this seems the same, but now the "denominations" of the coins can be different, too, is that right?

Comment: Yeah. T can contain any value as an item. Also, assumption is that both I and T are of same length.

Comment: If the denominations can be different. I ofcourse don't want to check all possible numbers. Can you give me a hint of how I can go around this?

Comment: You would need to start _constraining_ your problem in some way, for example, figuring out what are the _domains_ of your variables. You can then see _labelling_ which variable (giving it one of all possible values) reduces your search space the most. But this is what constraint programming is about. I guess you can't expect to get far without some math. How good is your math background?

Comment: I actually thought of an alternative, on T argument, if it has length 1, (do some code), else recurse on the rest of T?

Comment: "Do some code" sound like a great idea.

Comment: Indeed Boris. I've been struggling on this the entire day, and past day's could you please direct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My naive solution:

```
multSum(0, [], []).
multSum(S, [I | Is], [T | Ts]) :-
    between(0, S, T),
    S1 is S - I * T,
    multSum(S1, Is, Ts).
```

Sample output:

```
?- multSum(42, [6, 7, 8, 9], T).
T = [0, 0, 3, 2] ;
T = [0, 1, 1, 3] ;
T = [0, 6, 0, 0] ;
T = [1, 0, 0, 4] ;
T = [1, 4, 1, 0] ;
T = [2, 2, 2, 0] ;
T = [2, 3, 0, 1] ;
T = [3, 0, 3, 0] ;
T = [3, 1, 1, 1] ;
T = [4, 0, 0, 2] ;
T = [7, 0, 0, 0] ;
false.
```

Potential problems:

- This was just too easy; I must have overlooked something in your question or totally misinterpreted it.
- Tested in SWI Prolog only; relies on [between/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3). If necessary, you can [implement this predicate yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337235/can-you-write-between-3-in-pure-prolog).
- Limited to non-negative numbers.
- Exhaustively generates all possibilities, which can be quite a lot.
- Probably not the most efficient implementation possible...

Comment: What about negative integers?

Comment: @mat Allowing both positive and negative integers results in an infinite number of combinations, unless we agree on some (arbitrary) bounding. Example: `multSum(3, [1, -1], T)` should be satisfied by `T = [X, X-3]` for _every_ integer X. Likewise, `multSum(3, [1, 1], T)` yields `T = [X, 3-X]`.