# Implementing “for(+N1,+N2,+Step,N)” in prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking

The issue is when I implement this problem :

```
for(+N1,+N2,+Step,N)

for(1,7,2,N).
N=1;
N=3;
N=5;
N=7
true
```

The code i have done is :

```
for(N1,_,_,N1). 

for(N1,N2,Step,N):- N1 < N2, N1S is N1 + Step, for(N1S,N2,Step,N).
```

But when it runs it shows:

```
?- for(1,7,2,N).
N = 1 ;
N = 3 ;
N = 5 ;
N = 7 ;
false.
```

I think that in must show after `N=7;` the word `True`, but it appears `false`.
I think in the code i wrote, there is something i miss.

Comment: It's correct. `false` means that there is no more N that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I believe that as in the example, in the Execution it must appear 'True' after N=7;

Answer (score 1):

The `false` should not bother you; like @nhahtdh already pointed out, it is just there to inform you Prolog's backtracking engine ran out of paths.

But if you insist, it *is* possible to prevent the `false`, by using a cut.

```
for(N1, N2, Step, N1) :- N1 =< N2, N1 + Step > N2, !.
for(N1, N2, _, N1) :- N1 =< N2.
for(N1, N2, Step, N) :- N1S is N1 + Step, N1S =< N2, for(N1S, N2, Step, N).
```

Source: [Can you write between/3 in pure prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337235/can-you-write-between-3-in-pure-prolog#18338089)

Comment: Thanx,but I think is a bit more difficult by your way. Trying to find where the cut will be positioned in second line would take me too much time.

Answer (score -2):

My teacher told me another an easier way for implementing with `True` at the end.

```
for(N1,_,_,N1). 

for(N1,N2,Step,N):- N1 < N2, N1S is N1 + Step, for(N1S,N2,Step,N).

for(_,_,_,_).
```

Comment: You are rigth. Even it give me True, is flawed.