# Multiple values of a variable inbetween 0 and a number prolog

Tags: algorithm, variables, recursion, prolog, logic

So I've been trying to teach myself prolog and I think I'm coming along nicely. However, I'm sort of stuck at this one method I'm trying to make.

toN(N,A) A is equal to the integer values between 0 and N-1, generated in ascending order.

so 
toN(5,A) would be

```
A = 0;
A = 1;
A = 2;
A = 3;
A = 4.
```

I'm still new to prolog so I'm not exactly sure how to do this with multiple values. I had something like this:

```
toN(N,A) :- 0 < N, Nx is N-1, toN(Nx,A).
toN(N,A) :- 0 =< N, Nx is N-1, A = Nx.
```

However this just returns false. Nothing else. It seems perfectly fine to me

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337235/can-you-write-between-3-in-pure-prolog) may be helpful to you.

Comment: @DanielLyons I've been basing my procedures off that and have had no success. Could you take a look at what I'm doing?

Comment: `<=` to `=<`.  And, should `toN(0,A)` really succeed? And, exchange the clauses.

Comment: @false I did that and the only output is A=4.  No other values. In addition, I only want it to accept non-zero positive N, but I want it to list 0 as a value. How would I do that and fix the issue of a single value?

Comment: `toN(N,A) :- 0 < N, Nx is N-1, A = Nx`. as the last rule

Comment: Shoud have been `<` in place of  `=<`

Comment: @false I'm getting A = -1. now as my only value :/

Comment: Please look at my last response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the Prolog implementation that you are using supports [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

The implementation of `toN/2` gets declarative and super-concise:

```
toN(N,A) :- 
   A #>= 0, 
   A #<  N, 
   labeling([up],[A]).
```

You'll find more labeling options in the clpfd manual: [SWI-Prolog clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), [SICStus Prolog clpfd](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dclpfd.html).

Comment: Great solution, +1! `up` is the default in SICStus and SWI, so `indomain(A)` suffices in both systems.

Comment: Well just consider how inviting `indomain/1` is then: "`indomain/1`? What if I use `labeling/2`?" :-) Independently, I recommend to separate labeling from posting constraints, so that you can see residual goals.

Comment: I get that too! Sometimes four-liners definitely count as one-liners!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should generate the sequence of integers between any two arbitrary endpoints:

```
sequence(X,Y,X) :- % to generate the integers between X and Y,
  integer(X) ,     % - the starting point must be bound
  integer(Y) ,     % - the endpoint must be bound
  range(X,Y,Z)     % - then we just invoke the worker
  .                %

range(X,X,X) .  % hand back the last item in the sequence if X and Y have converged.
range(X,Y,X) :- % otherwise, return an item
  X =\= Y .     % - if X and Y haven't converged.
range(X,Y,Z) :- % otherwise, 
  X < Y ,       % - if X < Y ,
  X1 is X+1 ,   % - increment X
  range(X1,Y,Z) % - and recurse down.
  .             %
range(X,Y,Z) :- % otherwise
  X > Y ,       % - if X > Y
  X1 is X-1 ,   % - decrement X
  range(X1,Y,Z) % - and recurse down
  .             %
```

With that general-purpose tool, you can simply say:

```
to_n(N,A) :- sequence(0,N,A).
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo: `sequence(X,Y,X)` should be `sequence(X,Y,Z)` in the first line.

Comment: is this really the cleanest way to do it? I was looking for something that was a few lines of logical code. This seems a little far-fetched, But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation does not fail: by backtracking it yields numbers from `-1` to `N-1`

```
?- toN(5,A).
A = -1 ? ;
A = 0 ? ;
A = 1 ? ;
A = 2 ? ;
A = 3 ? ;
A = 4 ? ;
no
```

To eliminate the `-1` you should just replace `=<` by `<` in your second clause as @false commented above.

An alternative implementation, maybe more readable, would be

**Edit:** inserted condition `N>=0` in answer to @false comment below.

```
toN(N,A) :-
  N >= 0,
  toN(0,N,A).

toN(K,N,K).
toN(K,N,A) :-
  K < N-1,
  Kn is K+1,
  toN(Kn,N,A).
```

Comment: Does it make sense that `toN(-99,A)` succeeds?

Comment: @false It depends on how the problem is posed; but I agree a test makes the predicate more robust. Thanks.