# prolog - multiple outputs, same variable

Tags: prolog

How do I get the following program to produce the following output:

```
?- genN(3,R).
R=0;
R=1;
R=2;
```

My current output is just `R=0;`

code:

```
genN(1,0).
genN(N,R) :- 
    N > 1, 
    N1 is N-1, 
    genN(N1,R1),
    R is R1.
```

newer code:

```
genN(1,R):-R is 0.
genN(N,R) :- 
    N > 1, 
    N1 is N-1, 
    genN(N1,R),
    R is N1.
```

The above program is meant to output numbers from 0 to N-1.

Comment: `R is R1` so all variable `R` and `R1` are the same.

Comment: @false I added newer code with major changes to the original post. Now it gives me no output. only 'false'. Also updated the older code as well by replacing R1 but no output.

Comment: @false I was wondering how to get multiple outputs for one variable. When I printout R1 seems to be updating properly.

Comment: Last goals `genN(N1, R), R is N1`: Now you demand that the arguments are equal.

Comment: @false I still cannot get the desired output. Could you tell me what needs to change? I'm very new to prolog.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113105/multiple-values-of-a-variable-inbetween-0-and-a-number-prolog). But rather study [tag:successor-arithmetics].

Answer (score 1):

If your Prolog implementation supports [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), you could write `genN/2` like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

genN(Up,N) :-
    N #>= 0, 
    N #<  Up,
    indomain(N).
```

Sample query:

```
?- genN(3,N).
N = 0 ;
N = 1 ;
N = 2.
```