# How to use backtrack to increment a variable infinitely in Prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I am currently reading a Prolog book and I am stuck on one of the challenge exercises. I am meant to create a predicate with one argument. When this argument is a variable, it will return the following with backtracking, and X will continue to increment with no limit.

X = 0, X = 1, X = 2, X = 3, X = ...

I made the simple predicate below which backtracks through 0-2 but I can't figure out a way to make it continue infinitely.

```
backtracking_exercise(X) :-
    X = 0;
    X = 1;
    X = 2.
```

I was considering using the between/3 predicate but this would be only give a finite amount of numbers. I also experimented with the plus/3 predicate and recursion but no luck. This is what I have come up with, but as you can tell it is currently useless.

```
backtracking_excercise2(X) :-
    X = 0,
    plus(X,1,Y),
    backtracking_excercise2(Y).
```

Any tips on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `length(_,X)` is a fast way

Comment: @false Using `length/1` is also a terrible way given that it generates lists that will eventually need to be garbage collected.

Comment: @PauloMoura: Have you **measured** the actual "overhead"? It's completely neglectable. And it is much faster than the accepted answer...

Comment: @false This is a terrible way because it will crash when the integer is too big (`100,000,000` is small enough), even though the task solved is seemingly trivial.

Comment: @Fatalize: Could you please first measure the accepted solution for, say, 1000000? And, a system that crashes is broken by definition.

Comment: @false I'm not saying the accepted solution is good, I'm saying using `length` is not good either.

Comment: @Fatalize: There is not a single case where the accepted solution is better. That is a  difference worth noting.

Comment: For reference outside of exercise limitations, [here is a good implementation of that predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39259871/2554145).

Comment: @Fatalize: That still needs some extra work: In SWI it is 84 times slower, and in SICStus a factor of 11 for: `time( (positive_integer(N),N=100000) )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tail-recursive variant of Jim's solution:

```
plus(N) :-
    next_integer(1, N).

next_integer(I, I).
next_integer(I, K) :-
    J is I + 1,
    next_integer(J, K).
```

To prevent going into an infinite loop when the `plus/1` predicate is called with an instantiated argument, i.e. to make the predicate be only a generator, the first clause can be modified to:

```
plus(N) :-
    var(N),
    next_integer(1, N).
```

Comment: Failing for `plus(N), N = 1` is certainly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You had tagged your question with 'recursion' (since removed) and yet have implemented no recursion. I assume that this challenge is from a chapter on recursion, so I present the following hints (followed by a solution):

Hint 1:

What is the base case? If you want a recursive call to terminate it should have a base case.

> Your base case is `X = 0.`

Hint 2:

What is the recursive step? What do you need to do to the previous iteration in order to generate the next step in the sequence?

> Your step is `X is OldX + 1.`

A Solution:

> `plus(0).`
>  `plus(X) :- plus(N), X is N + 1.`

Additional info:

> This solution will go infinite for `plus(-1).` (and, indeed, all negative X). 
>  To avoid this, you'll need more advanced tools (such as `DCG` or `CLP(FD)`).