# Combing generator results and writing result to stream

Tags: prolog, prolog-defaulty, prolog-metainterpreter

Currently I can generate expression trees.

```
expression_tree([_|N_s],N_s, [number(0)]).
expression_tree([_|N_s0],N_s1, [op(neg),[E1]]) :-
    expression_tree(N_s0,N_s1, E1).
expression_tree([_|N_s0],N_s2, [op(add), [E1, E2]]) :-
    expression_tree(N_s0,N_s1, E1),
    expression_tree(N_s1,N_s2, E2).

generate_expression(N_c, E) :-
    length(N, N_c),
    expression_tree(N,[], E).

?- generate_expression(N,E).
N = 1,
E = [number(0)] ;
N = 2,
E = [op(neg), [[number(0)]]] ;
N = 3,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]] ;
N = 3,
E = [op(add), [[number(0)], [number(0)]]] ;
N = 4,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]]]] ;
N = 4,
E = [op(neg), [[op(add), [[number(0)], [number(0)]]]]] ;
N = 4,
E = [op(add), [[number(0)], [op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]] ;
N = 4,
E = [op(add), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]], [number(0)]]] ;
N = 5,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[op(neg), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]]]]]]
```

where N is the number of nodes for the tree.

I can also independently generate sequence numbers.

```
sequence_number(Sequence_number) :-
    sequence_numbers(1, Sequence_number).

sequence_numbers(I, I).
sequence_numbers(I, K) :-
    J is I + 1,
    sequence_numbers(J, K).

?- sequence_number(N).
N = 1 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 3 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 5 ;
N = 6
```

I can also generate and output the expressions but not with the correct sequence numbers

```
print_expression(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, E) :-
    write(Stream,Prefix),
    format(Stream, '~|~`0t~d~7+', Sequence_number),
    write(Stream,", "),
    write(Stream,E),
    write(Stream,Suffix),
    nl(Stream).

print_expressions_a(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, N) :-
    generate_expression(N, E),
    print_expression(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, E).

print_expressions_a :-
    Stream = user_output,
    Prefix = '(',
    Suffix = ')',
    Sequence_number = 1,
    N = 4,
    print_expressions_a(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, N).
```

```
?- print_expressions_a.
(0000001, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
true ;
(0000001, [op(neg),[[op(add),[[number(0)],[number(0)]]]]])
true ;
(0000001, [op(add),[[number(0)],[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]])
true ;
(0000001, [op(add),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]],[number(0)]]])
true ;
false.
```

Notice the sequence numbers are all `0000001`.

Which is generating choice-points, so I modified it using `forall`

```
print_expressions_b(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, N) :-
    forall(
        generate_expression(N, E),
        print_expression(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, E)
    ).

print_expressions_b :-
    Stream = user_output,
    Prefix = '(',
    Suffix = ')',
    Sequence_number = 1,
    N = 4,
    print_expressions_b(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, N).

?- print_expressions_b.
(0000001, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
(0000001, [op(neg),[[op(add),[[number(0)],[number(0)]]]]])
(0000001, [op(add),[[number(0)],[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]])
(0000001, [op(add),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]],[number(0)]]])
true.
```

which is still wrong.

---

The output I seek is

```
(0000001, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
(0000002, [op(neg),[[op(add),[[number(0)],[number(0)]]]]])
(0000003, [op(add),[[number(0)],[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]])
(0000004, [op(add),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]],[number(0)]]])
```

Where each sequence number is unique and sequential starting from `0` or `1` and can be written to a file. For this example the stream is set to `user_output` to simplify the question.

If I add the sequence number generator into the mix

```
print_expressions_c(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, N) :-
    generate_expression(N, E),
    sequence_number(Sequence_number),
    print_expression(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, E).

print_expressions_c :-
    Stream = user_output,
    Prefix = '(',
    Suffix = ')',
    N = 4,
    print_expressions_c(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, N).

?- print_expressions_c.
(0000001, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
true ;
(0000002, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
true ;
(0000003, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
true ;
(0000004, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
true ;
(0000005, [op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]])
true ;
```

the sequence numbers are now correct, but new expressions are never generated because the sequence number generator is using a choice point to generate the next sequence number and so the predicate `sequence_number`, does not backtrack to the `generate_expression` predicate to get a new expression.

So, can I use two generators that rely on backtracking in succession? If so, how?

### Supplement

This is related to my earlier questions on tree generators.
I am aware that this should be done with [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg), and that the data structure should be changed, but while I am trying to understand this, seeing it this way is easier to comprehend.

### Related SO Questions

- [What are the uses of the fail predicate in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584114/1243762)
- [How to use backtrack to increment a variable infinitely in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535804/1243762)
- [Algorithm improvement for enumerating binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633536/1243762)
- [How to enumerate combinations using DCGs with CLP(FD) and multiple constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42672512/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Rosetta Code - Prolog - Function_composition](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Function_composition#Prolog)

Comment: Can you present the essence? Do you mean how to do function composition or do you mean if you have `a(1). a(2). a(3). b(x). b(y). b(z).` then you somehow get `?- foo(A, B).` ---> `A = 1, B = x ; A = 2, B = y ; A = 3, B = z.` only with backtracking?

Comment: "Sorry, I don't understand your question." that makes two of us ;) you have link to how to do function composition is any language and there is an example of Prolog code that simply feeds the "output" of first predicate to the "input" of second predicate. Also composition in Prolog is for example `maplist(maplist, ...)` and this also works because it does the same.

Comment: No it will not work of course it will give you combinations, but I wanted to ask if this is what you mean, because what you show is too complex for me

Comment: Of interest: [A Couple of Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/prolog_misc/acomip.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/3_3.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Retracting backtracking

To summarize the question, you would like to:

- *generate* expressions using a generator that uses iterative deepening
- *number* each solution with consecutive integers.

Thus, the core problem you are facing is **preserving information over backtracking**.

This is of course **impossible** in pure Prolog: Doing so would *destroy* the most elementary properties we expect from relations, in particular our expectation that backtracking *undoes* everything that happened in the current branch of the computation.

A pure solution, therefore, is to **eliminate backtracking**!

I'm not joking: We will now change the entire search for solutions in such a way that each solution is found *without backtracking*, even though the program looks *as if* it used backtracking. In fact, the program will even *stay the same*, but we interpret it differently than plain Prolog would do it. This strategy allows us to *carry a counter* with us, and equip each solution we find with consecutive integers.

In essence, I am now implementing backtracking *within* Prolog, i.e., I am implementing backtracking *without* using Prolog's built-in mechanism for backtracking, so that I am free to extend it as I want.

## Reifying backtracking

> *to reify* = "to make it a thing" (from Latin: *res, rei* f. = matter, thing, affair)

First, I will represent the whole program differently, so that it easier to reason about it. The representation I shall use *avoids* the defaulty representation for regular Prolog goals, and instead uses *lists* of goals. I will represent each clause as a **fact** of the form:

```
head_body(Head, [Goal1,Goal2,...,Goaln]).
```

This change is purely syntactical (even though it helps enormously for further processing within our programs), and can be easily automated:

```
head_body(expression_tree([_|N_s],N_s, [number(0)]), []).
head_body(expression_tree([_|N_s0],N_s1, [op(neg),[E1]]),
          [expression_tree(N_s0,N_s1, E1)]).
head_body(expression_tree([_|N_s0],N_s2, [op(add), [E1, E2]]),
          [expression_tree(N_s0,N_s1, E1),
           expression_tree(N_s1,N_s2, E2)]).
```

We can *interpret* this program with a **meta-interpreter** like the following:

```
mi([G-[]|_], G).
mi([Gs0|Rest], G) :-
        findall(G0-Body, (Gs0 = G0-[First|Others],
                          head_body(First, Body0),
                          append(Body0, Others, Body)), Nexts, Rest),
        mi(Nexts, G).
```

Note that backtracking no longer occurs in this interpreter in the search for solutions, except for collecting all matching clauses, and actually *reporting* any solutions, which is only part of the interface but not of the core logic.

Note also that the `append/3` call can be *eliminated* by using list differences in the clause representation. I leave this as a very easy exercise.

To use this interpreter, we change our main predicate to read:

```
generate_expression(N_c, E) :-
        length(N, N_c),
        mi([E-[expression_tree(N,[],E)]], E).
```

Sample query:

```
?- generate_expression(N, E).
N = 1,
E = [number(0)] ;
N = 2,
E = [op(neg), [[number(0)]]] ;
N = 3,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]] ;
N = 3,
E = [op(add), [[number(0)], [number(0)]]] ;
N = 4,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]]]] .
```

This is **equivalent** to what you already have, and so it does not help a lot currently. By the way, maybe it is now a good time to get rid of this "have we got enough brackets yet" notation, so that future solutions are a bit easier to read. Consider for example terms of the form `op_arguments/2` to represent expressions, or better yet simply Prolog terms of the form `(+)/2` etc.

## Enumerating solutions

Now back to the main point: The key advantage of using a meta-interpreter is that it lets us **change** how plain Prolog would execute such programs.

In our case, now is the time to introduce a **counter** for solutions. Our first attempt could look like this:

```
mi(Alts0, S0, S, G) :-
        (   Alts0 = [G0-[]|Rest] ->
            (   S #= S0,
                G = G0
            ;   S1 #= S0 + 1,
                mi(Rest, S1, S, G)
            )
        ;   Alts0 = [Gs0|Rest],
            findall(G0-Body, ( Gs0 = G0-[First|Others],
                               head_body(First, Body0),
                               append(Body0, Others, Body)), Alts, Rest),
            mi(Alts, S0, S, G)
        ).
```

With the invoking predicate looking like this:

```
generate_expression(N_c, S, E) :-
        length(N, N_c),
        mi([E-[expression_tree(N,[],E)]], 0, S, E).
```

This **almost solves** the issue, but we still have the following problem:

```
?- generate_expression(_, S, _).
S = 0 ;
S = 0 ;
S = 0 ;
S = 1 ;
S = 0 ;
S = 1 ;
S = 2 ;
S = 3 ;
S = 0 ;
S = 1 ;
S = 2 ;
S = 3 ;
S = 4 ;
S = 5 ;
S = 6 ;
S = 7 ;
S = 8 ;
S = 0 ;
S = 1 .
```

So, solutions are enumerated, but there's *still* backtracking: The backtracking happens in `length/2`, and for each new length that is being tried, the counter is reset.

## Fair from the start

We therefore now change the interpreter to implement a **fair** computation strategy right from the start. By *fair*, we mean that every solution that exists is eventually *found*.

Iterative deepening is one such strategy. I leave this as an exercise, and implement **breadth-first search** in this example. Obtaining breadth-first search is easy: We simply **append** new alternatives. In fact, since we are now about to implement fairness as a fundamental property of the interpreter, we can also *simplify* the program to read:

```
head_body(expression_tree([number(0)]), []).
head_body(expression_tree([op(neg), [E1]]),
          [expression_tree(E1)]).
head_body(expression_tree([op(add), [E1, E2]]),
          [expression_tree(E1),expression_tree(E2)]).
```

A fair meta-interpreter, implementing breadth-first search *and* enumerating solutions:

```
mi(Alts0, S0, S, G) :-
        (   Alts0 = [G0-[]|Rest] ->
            (   S #= S0,
                G = G0
            ;   S1 #= S0 + 1,
                mi(Rest, S1, S, G)
            )
        ;   Alts0 = [Gs0|Rest],
            findall(G0-Body, ( Gs0 = G0-[First|Others],
                               head_body(First, Body0),
                               append(Body0, Others, Body)), Alts1),
            append(Rest, Alts1, Alts),
            mi(Alts, S0, S, G)
        ).
```

Our main predicate:

```
generate_expression(S, E) :-
        mi([E-[expression_tree(E)]], 0, S, E).
```

And here we go:

```
?- generate_expression(S, E).
S = 0,
E = [number(0)] ;
S = 1,
E = [op(neg), [[number(0)]]] ;
S = 2,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]] ;
S = 3,
E = [op(add), [[number(0)], [number(0)]]] ;
S = 4,
E = [op(neg), [[op(neg), [[op(neg), [[...]]]]]]] ;
S = 5,
E = [op(neg), [[op(add), [[number(0)], [number(0)]]]]] ;
S = 6,
E = [op(add), [[number(0)], [op(neg), [[number(0)]]]]] ;
S = 7,
E = [op(add), [[op(neg), [[number(0)]]], [number(0)]]] .
```

### Stay pure folks!

Using this **pure** approach to solve the issue gives us some hope to generalize this to other combinators, since the different concerns can be addressed in comparative isolation, and the original programs can stay the way they are.

Note also that I let the **toplevel** do the printing. If necessary, I can always write these solutions anywhere I want using impure predicates, but first and foremost each solution is available as a predicate argument that I can actually reason about *within* Prolog.

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, you need to use `library(clpfd)` to use CLP(FD) constraints. You should enable this by default, by putting it in your `.swiplrc`. This way, CLP(FD) constraints are available in all programs, like in GNU Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

from a purely pragmatic viewpoint, a counter it's easily implemented (in SWI-Prolog) with non backtrackable assigmnent:

```
print_expressions_d(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, N) :-
    generate_expression(N, E),
    inc(Sequence_number),
    print_expression(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, E).

print_expressions_d :-
    Stream = user_output,
    Prefix = '(',
    Suffix = ')',
    N = 4,
    nb_setval(counter,1),
    print_expressions_d(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, N).

inc(V) :- nb_getval(counter,V), C is V+1, nb_setval(counter,C).
```

Comment: I like how practical this is even though I would prefer to avoid using [nb_setval/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setval/2) and [nb_getval/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_getval/2). I will definitely check it out.

Comment: I looked at this example and the answer works correctly for the question. So then I extended the problem so that `N` counts down from 4 to 1 with an intermediate predicate that uses `is/2` and now it doesn't work. Seems that using `is/2` with `nb_getval` and `nb_setval` is affecting the backtracking. Will look at more, but might ask another question. Think of this as a comment for me if I come back to this in the future.

Comment: I think it's improbable that is/2 (itself not backtrackable) plays wrong with nb_... family. But yes, can't never tell for sure, the details can be really complicated...

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog  [is/2](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/master/src/pl-arith.c#L3478) source code

Answer (score -1):

```
/* --
1. use `bagof` to obtain a list of the solutions to query `generate_expression(N, E)` .
2. use recursion to :
    2a. iterate each item in the list .
    2b. then assign it a sequence number .
    2c. then print it  .
-- */

/*
example usage :

?- print_expressions_f .
(0000001, generate_expression(4,[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]]]))
(0000002, generate_expression(4,[op(neg),[[op(add),[[number(0)],[number(0)]]]]]))
(0000003, generate_expression(4,[op(add),[[number(0)],[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]]))
(0000004, generate_expression(4,[op(add),[[op(neg),[[number(0)]]],[number(0)]]]))
true ;
false.
*/

print_expressions_f :-
    Stream = user_output,
    Prefix = '(',
    Suffix = ')',
    N = 4,
    print_expressions_f(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, N).

print_expressions_f(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, N) :-
    Query = generate_expression(N, E) ,
    bagof(Query,Query,BagofE) ,
    print_expressions_f_every(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, BagofE) .

print_expressions_f_every(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, BagofE) :-
    print_expressions_f_each(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, BagofE, 10'1) .

print_expressions_f_each(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, BagofE, Sequence_number) :-
    [] = BagofE ,
    true .

print_expressions_f_each(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, BagofE, Sequence_number) :-
    [BagofE_head|BagofE_tail] = BagofE ,
    print_expression(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, Sequence_number, BagofE_head) ,
    Sequence_number_next #= Sequence_number + 1 ,
    print_expressions_f_each(Stream, Prefix, Suffix, BagofE_tail, Sequence_number_next) .
```

Comment: The predicates run to completion, but then `Not enough memory`.

Comment: @GuyCoder : it works fine for me (no "Not enough memory" problem) , tested on both swipl and yap .  The `10'1` is not a typo , it is the number `1` with base-10 explicitly specified .  For example `10'10 = 16'a` is true .

Comment: I checked it again with `10'1` and it seems to be working. However it is not outputting the in the correct format. This outputs `(0000003, generate_expression_3(4,[op(add),[[number(0)],[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]])` when the expected output I need is `(0000003, [op(add),[[number(0)],[op(neg),[[number(0)]]]]])` it adds `generate_expression_3` and `4,`

Comment: In regards to the format of the output -- the proposed solution above uses ``bagof(Query,Query,BagofE)`` . The `bagof` funkctor has a signature like ``bagof(Template,Goal,List)`` . ``Template`` provides the formation of each result that will end up in ``List`` . You can change the code above that currently reads ``bagof(Query,Query,BagofE)`` such that it becomes ``bagof(Template,Query,BagofE)`` and now you can define ``Template`` however you wish .

You could also (perhaps more simply) update ``print_expression`` to accomodate the term that it is being provided with ``BagOfE_head`` .