# Generate all pairs that sum to given number

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to generate all pairs X, Y that sum to given number Z using the following predicates:

```
genN(0).
genN(X) :- 
    genN(Xprev), 
    X is Xprev + 1.

sum2(X, Y, Z) :- 
    X + Y =:= Z.

allSum2(X, Y, Z) :- 
    genN(X), 
    X < Z, 
    genN(Y), 
    Y < Z, 
    sum2(X, Y, Z).
```

I'm using
`genN` to generate all natural numbers
`sum2` checks if given 3 numbers `X, Y, Z` then `X + Y = Z`.

Then the logic of `allSum2` is to
   generate all pairs X and Y such that `X` and `Y` are smaller than `Z` and
   to check if they sum up to `Z`.

Unfortunately I get stuck in generating infinitely many `Ys` and I do not understand why.

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Because `genN(Y)` is nested "deeper" in the `allSum2/3` predicate, and thus that is the first backtracking point. Yes `Y < Z` might let each attempt fail, but `genN/1` will keep suggesting new values, hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Why then when I ask
allSum2(X, Y, 5).
I do not see X = 0, Y = 5 as an answer?

Comment: Because then the `Y < Z` constraint fails, since `5 < 5` is false.

Comment: Of interest: [Combing generator results and writing result to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42904186/1243762) The question is broader than what you seek, but the accepted answer covers what you need.

Comment: This is ideally handled using CLP(FD): `addends(A1, A2, Sum) :- [A1, A2] ins 0..sup, A1 + A2 #= Sum, label([A1, A2]).` Call it as, `addends(X, Y, 5)`. Include additional constraints if you wish (like `A1 < A2`).

Comment: Basically one here perhaps should use *diagonal enumeration*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `diagonal enumeration` I think I know what you are talking about but a link would confirm it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is this it [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) ?

Comment: @GuyCoder no, it's the [other diagonals](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97610/2909), perpendicular to the Cantor's. Or [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html#v:diagonal). My code enumerates the diagonals down up, while the other code enumerates them top down AFAICS.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Leaning Haskell is on the list, but it keeps moving down. Makes you wonder what is getting put on the list ahead of Haskell?

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm sorry, that's what I've got on it right now. It's nothing fancy, we just take lists from the list of lists one-by-one, and order them in a jagged fashion. imagine we have a bunch of rows one under another; then we push row at index 1 from top (zero-based) 1 notch to the right, at index 2 -- 2 notches to the right, etc. then we collect the elements in the resulting columns,  top down. what we get are the diagonals. (I've edited my code in the first link to this effect, too, in the mean time).